# How to cancel a Google Workspace and redirect incoming emails

Tags: google-workspace, google

I'm shutting down my company and I have to cancel the Google Workspace associated to it, but many former customers will still try to reach out on my name@company.com email managed by Google Workspace.

Is there any way I can set an auto-reply or forward those emails to my personal@gmail.com email, even with Workspace canceled?

So far I can only find answers about forwarding/auto-replies on active workspace accounts.

EDIT to clarify the question: domain company.com is registered with another provider (namecheap) and we don't use the google hosting service. We only use workspace for emails, drive (data already transfered) and meet.

Comment: This depends on who is your domain registrar / domain hosting services provider. This question might belong to [webmasters.se] and [sf].

Comment: Thanks @Rubén, I added the requested details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent losing email messages due to the transition, before canceling Google Workspace for your domain, you should route the email from your domain registrar / domain hosting service provider.

I'm not familiar with **namecheap**. I suggest you go to their website, look for their support / contact options and ask them for help setting up the email forwarding for your domain.

The worst-case scenario is receiving guidance to complete the task independently, with resources to aid in the process.

Once you have confirmation that the email has been set to be forwarded and you have validated that it is working according to your needs, proceed to cancel Google Workspace. For this, follow the directions of [Cancel Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1257646?hl=en).

## Related

### Tags

[namecheap](/questions/tagged/namecheap), [domains](/questions/tagged/domains), [email](/questions/tagged/email)

### Questions

- [Should I set up standard email accounts? What are they?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/2030/52555)
- [Email forwarding to Gmail accounts instead of maintaining a mail server?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/54696/52555)
- [How to use Cloudflare and Namecheap email forwarding at the same time?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/37907/52555)